# Java: time difference in milliseconds using LocalDateTime and ChronoUnit

Tags: java, datetime

I want to calculate the time difference in milliseconds between two LocalDateTime objects:

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 250);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 252);
long diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startDate, endDate)
```

However, the value for diff is not 2, as I would expect, but 0. What's going on?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the last param there is actually nano seconds:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-int-int-int-int-

Switching to a diff of nanos output 2 in my case:

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 250);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 252);
long diff = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(startDate, endDate);

System.out.println(diff);
```

Yields:

```
2
```

I think that since you are comparing millis, the diff is being rounded down.

Answer (score 8):

The seventh argument to `LocalDateTime.of` is nanoseconds, not milliseconds.  Your times differ by .000002 of a millisecond, or zero to the nearest `long`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the between method of the Duration class.
as follows:

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 250);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 22, 21, 30, 30, 252);

Duration duration=Duration.between(startDate,endDate);
```